# Django TypeError: authenticate() takes exactly 0 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

`Django version 1.10.7`

I'm getting `TypeError: authenticate() takes exactly 0 arguments (3 given)`

Importing the authenticate() like this:
`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login`

Calling authenticate() like this :
`authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'] ,password=request.POST['password'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.10 `authenticate` does not take positional arguments ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate))
call it as

```
authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in : In the given example the authenticate is used like `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`

Comment: @batMan True, but pay attention to versions. In 1.11 Django added an optional request argument, but 1.10 did not have it.

Comment: Ok So that's optional only in 1.11. Makes sense. I just tried and it worked. Wish I could accept all 3 answers here. Anyways I have upvoted all of these. Thanks for a quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set the authenticate to a variable and don't pass in request, such as:

```
auth = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'] ,password=request.POST['password'])
```

And then use login to get the user logged in:

```
login(request, auth)
```

Don't forget to import login

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in : In the given example the authenticate is used like `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`

Comment: Wish I could accept all 3 answers here. Anyways I have upvoted all of these. Thanks for a quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use authenticate without the request, only takes username and password `authenticate(username=XXX,password=XXX)`. See the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#authenticate

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in : In the given example the authenticate is used like `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`

Comment: You are using Django version 1.10.7, the optional was added in version 1.11. Read the notes.

Comment: Wish I could accept all 3 answers here. Anyways I have upvoted all of these. Thanks for a quick answer.